# Add two exit buttons! FLASH as3

Tags: flash, button, exit

I know this may sound easy but i cant seem to figure out how to have two exit buttons. 
one at the front menu and one at the end menu. my front menu works however i cant seem to make the end one work.

Thanks

Code is for the front menu, it works well.

```
import flash.system.fscommand;

exit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, CloseApp);

function CloseApp(e:MouseEvent) {
    fscommand("quit");
}
```

Comment: All right in code. Check if your second exit button have the same instance name as first, or not handling press event (add trace in handler function)

Comment: `backExit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, CloseApp);` should do it if you have another clip/button named _backExit_ for example

Comment: "Duplicate function definition" i renamed the back button to backExit and used the same codes above to paste on the back button.

Comment: The "duplicate function definition" is probably because you have two `CloseApp()` functions now. You only need one ... George Profenza was suggesting you add that one line `backExit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, CloseApp);` only. This refers to the existing `CloseApp()` function that you already defined :)